# Why is only the first string giving the same remainder considered and the other paths eliminated in the following problem?

Tags: binary, numbers, digits

I recently read [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-binary-digit-multiple-of-given-number/).

The problem is about finding the smallest binary digit multiple of a given number x and the solution given there uses a binary tree starting from '1'. At each stage, it considers to topmost string and if it is not a multiple of x, it generates two more strings by concatenating a '0' and a '1' to the end of the string.

However, to optimize the solution the each possible solution s is checked for int(s) mod x.

If the remainder has occurred previously then that path is abandoned. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Comment: As this question deals directly with an article that has a comments section, it would make most sense for you to post your question there. Especially because your comment may be read by (and answered by) the author of the article.

Comment: actually there is no comment section

Comment: Geeks for Geeks does indeed have a comments section: https://imgur.com/xu8iQ3c.  You need to make sure that javascript is enabled in your browser.